# Setting up maven for selenium: Failed to execute goal - "C:\Users\java\client\src not found"

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I m trying to setup maven and selenium to write tests in Eclipse.

I m following instructions from selenium docs page. I run

### "mvn clean install" and it gives me this error -

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.
py_java_files) on project selenium-firefox-driver: An Ant BuildExceptio
ured: C:\Users\java\client\src not found.

can anyone help? apparently the standard installation instruction missed something.

EDIT:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
<name>selenium-firefox-driver</name>


<dependencies>


<dependency>
<groupId>commons-io</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency> 


</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
<!--
 See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin 
-->
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>copy_java_files</id>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<configuration>
<tasks>
<delete dir="src/main/java"/>
<copy todir="src/main/java" includeEmptyDirs="false">
<fileset dir="../../java/client/src">
<include name="org/openqa/selenium/firefox/**/*.java"/>
</fileset>
</copy>
</tasks>
</configuration>
<goals>
<goal>run</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
<execution>
<id>copy_resource_files</id>
<phase>generate-resources</phase>
<configuration>
<tasks>
<!--
 Extract everything but the *.class files and MANIFEST.MF from firefox.jar to target/classes ... 
-->
<unjar src="../../build/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/firefox.jar" dest="target/classes">
<patternset>
<exclude name="**/*.class"/>
<exclude name="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"/>
</patternset>
</unjar>
</tasks>
</configuration>
<goals>
<goal>run</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: How does your maven pom.file look?

Comment: @mylenereiners, here you go - take a look, i would really appreciate if you helped sort this out...

Comment: Your maven pom is way too complex :) Will post an easier one. The only thing(s) I need to know is your program name to fill the right group and artifact id's in the pom.

Comment: @mylenereiners, thx! sure: my program name will be : groupId  - testing_naimikz, artifactId - erjan_test_naimikz_selenium

Comment: @mylenereiners, and i want to write test for firefox driver! i m testing my website on firefox first..

Comment: what does ../../java/client/src means? is it expected to be C:\\Users\\java\\client?? or a folder under ${basedir}/src/main/java?

Answer (score 1):

Example pom (just the selenium part, make sure you add dependencies you need...)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testing.naimikz</groupId>
    <artifactId>erjan_test_naimikz_selenium</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>erjan's example selenium program</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.2</version>
                 <configuration>
                     <source>1.8</source>
                     <target>1.8</target>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

- please check your java version (I presumed - see compiler plugin - that it was 1.8.
- you don't need to include anything for Firefox. That is included with selenium.
  In your code you need something like

  ```
   WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
  ```

(and ctrl-shift-o will then import the right jar :))